# Cisco anyconnect for MAC, .xml file with profile. Where should I place it?

Tags: macos, cisco-anyconnect

I have a MacBook M2 with macOS Monterrey, I want to connect to a network through Cisco anyconnect, they sent me an `.xml` file with the profile.

Where should I put it? In which folder should I put it? I would appreciate if anyone has the full path to get to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

The XML should be located on `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile`.

You need to restart anyconnect (or reboot the computer).

Reference :
[Cisco VPN AnyConnect Profile Locations](https://commons.lbl.gov/display/itfaq/Cisco+VPN+AnyConnect+Profile+Locations).

Answer (score -1):

I've found `.anyconnect_global` file in `/opt/cisco/anyconnect`, looks like this is what are you looking for.

```
cd /opt/cisco/anyconnect
ls -lAtr
cat .anyconnect_global
```